# PostgreSQL SSL root.crt not loading

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, public-key, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9 on Ubuntu (from their PPA repository). I am using OpenSSL 0.9.8o.

I have generated keys and certificates using TinyCA2 for both a pg server and the psql client. I essentially followed the [instructions](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/ssl-tcp.html).

My pg_hba.conf file is configured with this:

```
 hostssl all             abc             ::1/128              cert        clientcert=1
```

I have put the root certificate generated by TinyCA along with the server's certificate and key in the DATA directory as follows.

```
sudo unzip database_server.zip
sudo mv sudo mv cacert.pem root.crt
sudo mv cert.pem server.crt
sudo openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key
sudo chmod 0600 server.key
sudo chmod ga=r root.crt
sudo chown postgres:postgres root.crt server.key server.crt
```

Yet I am unable to start the server. This is what I get on startup:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start 9.0
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.0 database server
* The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
  2011-03-17 16:39:13 IST LOG:  client certificates can only be checked if a root certificate store is available
  2011-03-17 16:39:13 IST HINT:  Make sure the root.crt file is present and readable.
  2011-03-17 16:39:13 IST CONTEXT:  line 93 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.0/main/pg_hba.conf"
  2011-03-17 16:39:13 IST FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

Interestingly, the root.crt file is very much present and readable:

```
$ ll
<snip>
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres  143 2010-12-01 17:06 pg_ctl.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres 4.3K 2011-03-17 16:35 pg_hba.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres 1.7K 2011-03-17 15:58 pg_ident.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres  18K 2011-02-07 18:38 postgresql.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 2.8K 2011-03-17 16:39 root.crt
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 2.2K 2011-03-17 14:37 server.crt
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  891 2011-03-17 16:18 server.key
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  963 2011-03-17 14:37 server.key.encrypted
```

What is going on? What do I have to do for this certificate to load???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permissions are OK. I have working:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 postgres postgres  615 2011-04-25 16:23 root.crt
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  692 2011-04-25 17:20 server.crt
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  887 2011-04-25 17:17 server.key
```

Try to put this files in data directory (/var/lib/postgresql/9.0/{clustername}), not config directory (/etc/postgresql/9.0/{clustername}).

When cluster is created there are automatically provided snakeoil server.key and server.crt in data directory, but there is no root.crt. Probably you put your certs in config directory.

> To start in SSL mode, the files
>   server.crt and server.key must exist
>   in the server's data directory. These
>   files should contain the server
>   certificate and private key,
>   respectively. If the private key is
>   protected with a passphrase, the
>   server will prompt for the passphrase
>   and will not start until it has been
>   entered.
>
> To require the client to supply a
>   trusted certificate, place
>   certificates of the certificate
>   authorities (CA) you trust in the file
>   root.crt in the data directory.

In Ubuntu:

```
cat /etc/postgresql/9.0/main/postgresql.conf | grep data_dir
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.0/main' # use data in another directory
```